# Is it possible to test $x > c$ and $y > c$ using only one condition?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to test $x > c$ and $y > c$ using only one condition?

If it's not possible within $(-\infty,+\infty)$, is it possible in $[0,1]$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you define as "one condition"?

Comment: $\min(x,y) > c$?

Comment: Please avoid "writing questions in the title". I have also reformatted the mathematical parts into $\LaTeX$ to improve readability.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know if $\min\{x,y\}>c$.

We can write: $$\min\{x,y\} = \frac{x+y}2 - \frac{|x-y|}2$$

Now it is simple to verify if both $x,y$ are bigger than $c$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for *universality*

$\rm\: a < b,c \iff a < min\{b,c\}\ $

$\rm\: a\ \ |\ \ b,c \iff a\ \ |\ \ \gcd\{b,c\}$

$\rm\: a\subset b,c \iff a\subset \  b\ \cap\  c $